# How to divide data in excel into 4 columns whose sum is almost equal to 1/4 of the sum of all values/

Tags: excel

I have this set of numbers.

74, 15, 60, 5, 61, 56, 4, 23, 47, 66, 20, 54, 39, 9, 34, 37, 45, 93, 85, 79, 4, 76, 85, 51, 78, 60, 95, 50, 79, 62, 21, 75, 18, 5, 79, 46, 76, 92, 11, 100, 51, 39, 80, 92, 95, 20, 62, 1, 22, 69, 65, 45, 34, 42, 40, 8, 29, 82, 38, 9, 100, 78, 22, 11, 57, 71, 38, 35, 37, 32, 19, 58, 91, 90, 91, 26, 38, 85, 96, 3, 80, 18, 32, 74, 97, 60, 65, 85, 92, 38, 12, 31, 37, 76, 84, 9, 17, 33, 20, 19

I would like to divide this set of numbers into 4 parts/columns in excel so that their sum is as close as possible to 1/4 of the value of all numbers

Comment: Using a spreadsheet is not always the best solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How would you manually do it? What have you tried? Please, read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: ' as close as possible to 1/4 of the value of all numbers'. I don't understand this specification. Could you clarity?

Comment: Does each column of the output need to have the same number of numbers (or as close as possible?)

Comment: I arrived at 2.5. If you want to know how, please add your efforts to your question :-)

Comment: You can get the following results: 1263, 1262, 1262, 1262 - 5 min to do this manually. Add 4 numbers to each row and then add the next set of 4 numbers going down the list. Keep a running total for each column, as you add next 4 numbers swap them around to keep the running totals as close as possible. At the end look for numbers that you can switch between columns to get to the closest match. This type of question would go down well on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Total of all numbers is 5049. 1/4 equals 1262.25 .
Is the sort of thing you're after?

All those numbers, sorted numerically, then added to columns, the totals almost matching to a quarter of the total...

[image: 4 columns of totals of an array]